# Get today and previous available date data in a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have following table data for processing.

```
SYMBOL    DATE        OPENVALUE        CLOSEVALUE
-------------------------------------------------
ABC       2019-01-01  10               15
ABC       2019-01-02  17               19
ABC       2019-01-03  13               20
ABC       2019-01-04  18               30
ABC       2019-01-07  25               45
ABC       2019-01-08  40               50
```

I want to process and display information as follow

```
SYMBOL        DATE        OPENVALUE        PREVDAYCLOSINGVALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------
ABC           2019-01-01  10               NA
ABC           2019-01-02  17               15
ABC           2019-01-03  13               19
ABC           2019-01-04  18               20
ABC           2019-01-07  25               30
ABC           2019-01-08  40               45
```

If anyone can help. I am facing problem with inner joining current date with previous available date data.

Comment: There's no need to SHOUT your subject at everyone; we can read you fine. :)

Comment: Thank for correction, did it in a hurry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(closevalue) over (partition by symbol order by date) as prev_closevalue
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LAG()`.

The 3-argument form lets you specify a default value. I would not recommend `'NA'`, since it does not have the same datatype as the other values (which looks like positive integers), so I used `-1`.

```
SELECT 
    t.*, 
    LAG(OPENVALUE, 1, -1) OVER(PARTITION BY [SYMBOL] ORDER BY [DATE]) AS PREVDAYCLOSINGVALUE
FROM mytable t
```